# Messages beta hangs. How to remove it or at least its accounts?

Tags: performance, bug, messages

I've received a huge iMessage and now the App hangs. I can't remove the App, because it's only possible via the menu item which is not responding. Removing `~/Documents/iChat/*` and `~/Library/Messages/*` didn't help either.

Any ideas of how to remove it or at least its accounts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to remove `com.apple.iChat` and `com.apple.Messages` in `~/Library/Caches` to get it working normally.

Answer (score 1):

Messages always hang on my Mac as well, error telling me no account set up etc, and restarting my Mac always helps to bring it back to normal.

Comment: And how does this relate to the specific issue (big iMessage) raised in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Navigate to `/Applications/`
2. Right-Click on *Messages.app*
3. Choose *Get Info* and **uncheck** the option to *Open in 32-bit Mode*.

Messages should open normally, and then you can Uninstall as usual.

Comment: This is already unchecked and didn't helped. The problem was the message flood.